# UIPageViewController - how to customize left and right page in landscape mode?

Tags: xcode, ipad, uipageviewcontroller

I have a page-based application in Xcode and I am trying to set it up so that the left page and right page have different layouts in landscape mode.

Specifically, I want to set a different page bg image if the page is the on the left side, so that it looks more like a real book.

Is there a way to programmatically detect if a UIPageViewController is on the left or right side in landscape mode?  How would you go about solving this problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a property for the background image, you can change it on the viewControllerAtIndex

```
 - (YourPageContentViewController *)viewControllerAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index {   
   // Return the data view controller for the given index.
   if (([self.modelArray count] == 0) || (index >= [self.modelArray count])) {
       return nil;
   }
   YourPageContentViewController *dataViewController [[YourPageContentViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"YourPageContentViewController" bundle:nil];
   if (index%2 ==0) {
      //set a background
      dataViewController.backgroundImage = imageForLeftSide;
   } else {
      //set the other background
      dataViewController.backgroundImage = imageForRightSide;
   }
   dataViewController.dataObject = [self.modelArray objectAtIndex:index];
   return dataViewController; 
}
```